# Problem installing Tk module perl in MacOS catalina

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, perl-module, cpan

I got the following errors while installind Tk module from perl in MacOS catalina 10.15.6

```
cpan install Tk
```

And the error I get

```
Cannot find '/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h' have you installed /usr/bin/perl?
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 39.
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  SREZIC/Tk-804.035.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

Could you please help me know what's happening here?

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql/issues/41) issue. It seems like `perl.h` is located in an unexpected place. On my mac (10.15.5) I have system perl version 5.18 and `perl -MConfig -E'system "ls $Config{archlib}/CORE"'` shows only a single file `libperl.dylib` (usually `perl.h` is located here). However, `perl.h` exists in here `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE` instead but Tk cannot find it since it is not in the usual place

Comment: To add to the above comment, `perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{archlib}'` shows `/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level`

Comment: Also the Tk [Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/source/SREZIC/Tk-804.035/Makefile.PL) requires a file `myConfig` which checks for `perl.h` in `$Config{archlibexp}` see [line 3](https://metacpan.org/source/SREZIC/Tk-804.035/myConfig#L3). Maybe the easiest solution would be to use `perlbrew`, then you would get all the headers in the right place ?

Comment: I tried to install Tk with perlbrew perl version 5.30.1, but it seems like it also requires libX11, see [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7022116) for more information